# Why might this use of new cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, ctypes

If I use placement new in the following way my code appears to run reliably. If I use the commented code instead I frequently get either a segmentation fault (11) or unexpected results. Returning the address of a statically allocated object also works.

I've verified that null is not returned and that this function is being called exactly once for the single Python object in my test script.

```
extern "C"
{    
    void * hail_detector_new()
    {
        alignas(alignof(hail::Detector)) static U8 allocation[sizeof(hail::Detector)];

        // return new(std::nothrow) hail::Detector;

        return new(allocation) hail::Detector;
    }
}
```

Python arguments and return type declarations:

```
f = _library.hail_detector_new

f.restype = c_void_p

f.argtypes = None

class Detector(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._object =  _library.hail_detector_new()
```

Versions

```
Squall: clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Squall: python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Comment: [Off Topic] You might want to consider using [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead like `static aligned_storage_t<sizeof(hail::Detector), alignof(hail::Detector)> allocation;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Nice.